# Help with moving codeigniter to a new server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a bit of a problem. I am duplicating my website to a test environment on a new server with a new domain.

I have it working fine with the database etc but here is my error.

On the live site if I click suppliers it goes to the page fine If I click it on the test environment it does not work.

These are two links

http://wvtest.co.uk/

http://theweddingvine.com/

The code to create the link is as follows:

```
<?php 
  echo anchor('search', 'Suppliers'); 
?>
```

The file and the folders are the same. Is there something in codeigniter which can direct the link ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify application/config/config.php and set:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/";
```

That will make your links work on either server.

Answer (score 0):

have you specified the correct **base_path** for your testing server in **application/config/config.php file?**

Check that please, this is the case mostly in such problems.

Comment: Should I be changing the following 

ABSPATH

Answer (score 0):

You could change your base_url to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://wvtest.co.uk/';
```

or

```
$config['base_url'] = '/';
```